# Find amount of rows in a data table without looping C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, datatable

I currently have a piece of code that works fine, listed below:

```
 foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                if ((int)dr["StatusId"] == 1)
                {
                  count += 1;

                }

            }
```

I then create an array using count as the length of my new array and cycle back through an identical loop to populate the array. Is there a way that I can do something to get the amount of of rows in the data table without creating the original loop so I can clean up my code some?

Comment: Give 'Rows.Count' a Chance --- added as answer

Comment: @nabuchodonossor There is an if in the loop

Comment: icount int = dt.Rows.Count

Comment: do you want the count of all rows? or just rows with a status If of 1?

Comment: @nabuchodonossor: What if **StatusId** == 0, `Rows.Count` will count that row to?

Comment: @SuprabhatBiswal: yeah ... than you will have to use one of the another answers.

Comment: @nabuchodonossor: You could that part too in your answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soo... if I read your question correctly, you are not looking for a way to count the rows, but you are looking for a way to get an array of rows matching your criterium?

Try this:

```
DataRow[] result = dt.Select("StatusId = 1");
```

The method `Select` selects all rows matching your criterium and returns an array of the selected rows.

See also: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This answer was able to completely take away both of my loops in one line - pretty sweet.

Answer (score 4):

If you simply want the count of all rows in the table, `dt.Rows.Count` will do the trick.

However, if you need to interrogate the value of `StatusId` and only count the row if `StatusId == 1`, then you will somehow need to loop the rows. You could do this using Linq and avoid manually writing the loop:

```
var count = dt.AsEnumerable().Count(r => r.Field<int>("StatusId") == 1);
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use linq features for doing this. In your example I noticed that you try to count "StatusId" column with condition. For counting specific conditions you can use the method below.

```
DataTable myDataTable = new DataTable();
int countOfCondition = myDataTable.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<int>("StatusId") == 1).Count();
```

Answer (score 2):

Here as answer @erikscandola: the if is clearly to be omitted, you don´t Need to count ...

```
  Rows.Count
```

Comment: You need to count only the rows with `StatusId` equals to 1. Your solution returns the total number of rows regardless of `StatusId` value.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the count of rows where StatusId = 1 you could use Linq:

```
public void Test()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    int count = (from DataRow dr
                in dt.Rows
                 where (int)dr["StatusId"] == 1
                 select dr
                ).Count();

    //on one line
    int count = (from DataRow dr in dt.Rows where (int)dr["StatusId"] == 1 select dr).Count();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

rows.Length or rows.Count should work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `AsEnumerable` exstension and then use where to get only rows that have `StatusId` equals to 1. After this use `Count` to get the number of results.

```
dt.AsEnumerable().Where(dr => (int)dr["StatusId"] == 1).Count();
```